# What's the difference between re.findall() and str.count('str')?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the difference between re.findall() and str.count('str')?
Beside that

```py
str.count('str')
```

returns the number of appearances

and

```py
 re.findall(pattern, 'str')
```

returns a list with each appearance.

What's the benefit of each? When should I choose each?
Which method is preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not the same. Consider the following example:

```
>>> a = "123strxyz"
>>> a.count("str.")
0
>>> re.findall("str.", a)
['strx']
```

[`findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) accepts a regex, so in the second example, it finds "strx" in the string, while the `count` function doesn't find the actual dot (since it tries to match the literal dot).